# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el parámetro declarado en la línea de comandos?

Tags: cmd, batch

quiero hacer que el usuario haga algo como esto:

```
comando texto="un texto"
```

he intentado esto:

```
@echo off
set x=%texto
echo %x%
```

pero no funciona

alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un script DOS Batch la forma de leer los parámetros pasados por linea de comando es usando las claves `%0`, `%1`, ... `%9`. Dónde `%0`es el nombre del script y los parámetros en si comienzan con `%1`. Puede probarlo así:

```
@echo off
echo Nombre del script:  %0
echo Parametro 1      :  %1
echo Parametro 2      :  %2
```

**Importante**

Hay varios caracteres que por defecto se consideran delimitadores, por ejemplo, en tu caso el `=` se considera delimitador, por lo que `texto="un texto"` se consideran dos parámetros distintos:

```
%1 = texto
%2 = "un texto"
```

> **Delimitadores**
>
> traducido desde https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php
>
> Algunos caracteres de la línea de comandos son ignorados por los
>   archivos por lotes, dependiendo de la versión del DOS, de si se
>   "escapan" o no, y a menudo dependiendo de su ubicación en la línea de
>   comandos:
>
> - las comas (",") son reemplazadas por espacios, a menos que sean parte de una cadena entre comillas
> - los punto y coma (";") se reemplazan por espacios, a menos que sean parte de una cadena entre comillas
> - Los caracteres "=" a veces son reemplazados por espacios, no si son parte de una cadena entre comillas.
> - la primera barra inclinada ("/") es reemplazada por un espacio sólo si sigue inmediatamente a la orden, sin un espacio de avance
> - los espacios múltiples son reemplazados por un solo espacio, a menos que sean parte de una cadena entre comillas
> - las espacios iniciales son reemplazadas por un solo espacio que conducen a los espacios antes de que el primer argumento de la línea
>     de comando sea ignorado
> - los espacios que quedan después del último argumento de la línea de comandos se recortan
>
> Tenga en cuenta, sin embargo, que estas "características" pueden
>   variar con los sistemas operativos utilizados. Se puede encontrar más
>   información sobre el análisis sintáctico de la línea de comandos en
>   las páginas PATH y FOR (especialmente los ejemplos interactivos de
>   FOR).